# The value of an investment in Canada Savings Bonds is modelled by $A(t) = A_0 e^{0.0255t}$... Rest of question below.

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, applications

The value of an investment in Canada Savings Bonds is modeled by $$A(t) = A_0 e^{0.0255t}$$, where A is the amount the investment is worth after $t$ years, and $A_0$ is the initial amount invested. At what rate, correct to 3 decimal places, is the investment growing at the time when its value has doubled?

I understand that we have to find the derivative but how can we find it if we don't know an initial amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for rate *when the investments value has been doubled* or when

$$A(t)=2A_0 = A_0 e^{0.0255t}$$
So the initial value cancels and you have:
$$
2=e^{0.0255t}\Rightarrow \ln(2)=0.0255t\Rightarrow t=\frac{\ln(2)}{0.0255}
$$
Now, taking the derivative:
$$A'(t)=0.0255A_0e^{0.0255t}\Rightarrow A'(\frac{\ln(2)}{0.0255})=0.0255A_0e^{0.0255(\frac{\ln(2)}{0.0255})}\\
=.0255A_0e^{\ln(2)}=2(.0255)A_0=.051A_0$$
Which does depend on the principal, as it should.

Comment: That is the time when the investment will have doubled; not the rate at which it is growing.

Comment: I have edited in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just set $A_0e^{(0.0255t)}=2A_0$, divide by $A_0$ and you get $2=e^{(0.0255t)}$. Use the natural log to find what the value of t is at this time (it's 27.182). Take the derivative of $A(t)$, plug in 27.182 you get $A'(27.182)=A_0(.0255)e^{(.0255)(27.182)}$. Compute that and it's your answer. It'll be some number multiplied by $A_0$.

Comment: much simpler answer if you avoid computing $t$ early

Answer (score -1):

You have $A = 2A_0 \implies 2A_0 = A_0e^{0.0255t} \implies e^{0.0255t} = 2\implies 0.0255t = \ln 2 \implies t = \dfrac{\ln 2}{0.0255}$. To find the rate, we have: $A'(t) = 0.0255A_0e^{0.0255t} \implies A'\left(\frac{\ln 2}{0.0255}\right) = 0.0255A_0e^{0.0255\cdot \left(\frac{\ln 2}{0.0255}\right)} = 0.0255A_0e^{\ln 2} = 0.051A_0$.

Comment: That is the time when the investment will have doubled; not the rate at which it is growing.